# Informix 'not in' returns confusing result

Tags: sql, informix

I have a puzzling problem:
consider two tables mtst with field m21_nr and mlag with field m22_tsnr.
both tables contain several thousand records, some of them start with an 'M'

the query

```
select m21_nr from mtst where m21_nr like "M%"
```

returns roughly 500 results

```
SELECT m22_tsnr FROM mlag where m22_tsnr like "M%";
```

return 50 results

I want to find all numbers in mtst which are not in mlag

```
select m21_nr
from mtst
where m21_nr like "M%"
and m21_nr not in (select m22_tsnr from mlag  where m22_tsnr like 'M%')
```

seems to work.
But when I leave away the where clause in the select

```
select m21_nr
from mtst
where m21_nr like "M%"
and m21_nr not in (select m22_tsnr from mlag)
```

I get an empty result!!!!!!! It seems that the missing numbers suddenly appeared?
I already checked the types - both varchar(25) and I used trim around the fields to be sure that no whitespaces are spoiling the result.

It must be a simple stupid mistake, but I do not find the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue could be with `null` values in `m21_nr` and `m22_tsnr` columns in those tables. So when you use `not in`, it is equivalent to saying

```
  m21_nr <> someval and m21_nr <> someval1 and ..m21_nr <> null
```

When it encounters `null` in the column, it evaluates to `unknown` and the condition becomes `unknown`. So you don't get any rows in the result.

You might have to explicitly say `m22_tsnr is not null` in the `where` clause.

Comment: Ran into this before myself. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750701/2-queries-that-should-return-the-same-data-but-dont

Comment: thank you very much! That was definitely the solution!